# Open webpush notification url in a popup window

Tags: push-notification, service-worker, addeventlistener, web-push, service-worker-events

I am using Django-Webpush to send push notifications to users, where clicking on the notifications it opens the URL in a new tab.

What I want to do is to open the URL in a new popup window similar to:

```
window.open(href,'height=500,width=800,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');
```

I have searched and I cannot find a way to do this with self.clients.openWindow(). It simply opens the URL in a new tab, which is not useful to me.

Is there a way or an alternative to use in the notification event listener?

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event){
 event.waitUntil(
   event.preventDefault(),
   event.notification.close(),
   self.clients.openWindow(event.notification.data.url)
   );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a deep research on the matter, I discovered there is currently (December 2020) no way for the openWindow() to open the notification link in a new window. It will always force the url to open in a new tab.